# Popover inside table responsive being clipped

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, datatables

Bootstrap 3, popovers are clipped within tables which are wrapped in `table-responsive`. I've tried a number of things such as setting the `table-responsive` class to `overflow-y: visible;` but nothing has helped. Hope someone can point me in the right direction.

[image]

**Edit:** Not sure if this makes any difference, but I'm also using Datatables to display the table. Although, I honestly can't see any issues from that end.

**Edit2:** https://jsfiddle.net/ujj3zkdq/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add z-index to the pop up element. ex: **z-index:1111;**

> Update:
>
> **Replace the function with this. You can change the placement as top, right, left or auto.**

```
$(function() {
    $('table').DataTable({
       paging: false,
       searching: false,
       lengthChange: false
    });

    $('[data-toggle=popover]').popover({
       placement: "right",
       trigger: 'focus'
    });
});
```

Comment: @adamj Can you please share a fiddle so that it is easy to fix.

Comment: Hey Abhay, added jsfiddle link up the top for everyone. Looks to be a Datatables issue, but */scratches head* not sure where or why.

Comment: Thanks Abhay. This is more of a workaround than a fix for the issue, but I'll take it. I'll mark this as an answer if no else has any ideas into making it work with top placed popovers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115792/discussion-between-abhay-naik-and-adamj).

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `container` property of your popover to `'body'` which sets your popover's container to the `<body>` tag. Like this:

```
$('#myPopover').popover({container: 'body'});
```

or

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="popover" data-container="body" title="Popover Header" data-content="Some content inside the popover">Toggle popover</a>
```

Read more here http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_popover.asp

Comment: Tried this one as well, but when you scroll through the table it moves the popover around the place.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add Option `container: "body"` , it will work

```
$(document).popover({
    selector: '[data-toggle=popover]',
    html: true,
    trigger: 'focus',
    container: "body"
});
```